# Magento 2 project

Tags: git

I it advised to store all magento files in project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/dev_install.html

The git repository is for "anyone who contributes to the Magento codebase. If that isn’t you, go back and [choose another starting point](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/continue.html)."